# Vim - Find pattern on currently line ONLY

Tags: vim, macros

I'm wondering if there is a way to find a pattern, but restrict it to the current line. Basically, the equivalent of `/PATTERN` but restricted to the current line, rather than the entire document.

I've tried `:s/PATTERN`, but that deletes the pattern from the line and places my cursor at the beginning of the line, which is not at all what I need. I was hoping you could search without replacing...

I'm hoping to use this for a macro in order to place my cursor at the start of that pattern, as would happen when you do `/PATTERN` on the entire file, so anything that is macro-friendly is even better.

Any vim users out there that might have an idea?

EDIT: `0/PATTERN` in a macro would work for my current need, but I'm hoping there's a more specific way to restrict the search.

ANSWER: There's a few ways posted in here so far, but the one I like best right now is using `Shift+V` to select the current line visually, followed by `/\%V` to search only in the visual selection. Then `Shift+V` again will turn off the visual mode.

Comment: My knowledge about macro is limited, but interactively, you can select current line with `Shift + V`, and then do `/search`.

Comment: That worked. If you want to post that as an answer, I can accept it. I did `Shift+V/\%VPATTERN` and it's working

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My knowledge about macro is limited, but interactively, you can select current line with `Shift + V`, and then do `/\%Vsearch` (see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\%V).

Comment: This is probably my favorite. I did not know that \%V worked in normal / searching! Will be very helpful for restricting the search space.

Comment: This does not work on all cases. It is pretty much the same as `/search` without visual line mode

Comment: @PeterRincker could give an example or a source where i can found cases where this don't work?

Comment: @snap, I was too hasty here. I believe it is a great method. It could be tricky for a pattern that goes across the visual boundary. Although, I doubt this will be an issue for such a limited case

Answer (score 10):

```
/\%9lsearch
```

Where `\%9` means line number 9.

Typing in the line number is still a bit lame. You can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> followed by a vim expression and <kbd>enter</kbd> to evaluate the vim expression and insert its output. `line('.')` will return the line of the cursor.

In one complete step

```
/\%<c-r>=line('.')<cr>lsearch
```

For more help see:

```
:h /\%l
:h i_CTRL-R
```

Comment: Can you expand upon this? I've tried it and I'm 100% sure I'm not entering it properly. Perhaps show how that single step approach works? It looks helpful, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 10):

try to Find first character of the Pattern by typing

```
f <letter>
```

It's not exactly what you need but can help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 9):

1. Place the cursor on the line you want to search in
2. Select it with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
3. Type <kbd>/</kbd> to begin searching
4. Prefix your term with `\%V`, e.g. `\%Vabc` to search for `abc` in only the visually selected blocks (in our case the single line)

[image: vim screencast]

Answer (score 3):

You can search without replacing by using

```
:s/PATTERN//gc
```

Then press <kbd>n</kbd> to skip the replacement.  If the pattern is not found, you won't even be asked.

You could also just highlight the current line or the range of lines.

Comment: The buffer will have to be modifiable for this to work so it will not work in builtin help for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the number of occurrences in the current line, you can use the flags `g` and `n` for `:[range]s[ubstitute]/pattern/string/[flags]`:

```
:s/pattern//gn
```

If you specify no range, the default is the current line.

When you press first `*` on the word you want to count, you can abbreviate to following

```
:s///gn
```